# BDD Cucumber tests via jUnit

Tags: java, spring, testing, cucumber, bdd

I there any examples for runing cucumbers via jUnit manually?

I have a simple empty class with @RunWith(Cucumber.class) which has all my feature files.

```
import cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class RunCukesTest {
}
```

And simple junit test running it:

```
@Test
    public void cucumberFirstPartTests()throws Exception{
        Cucumber cucumber = new Cucumber(RunCukesFirstPart.class);
        RunNotifier notifier = new RunNotifier();
        cucumber.run(notifier);
    }
```

Is there any examples at all for filtering manually tests, using runner scheduler and descriptions of tests for cucumbers? Watched documentation, but for me it is not enough. I will appreciate any links. Thank you.

Comment: Not enough detail here. Post relevant snippets of your Spring config & Test classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark each Scenario/Feature with any number of tags, using `@TAGNAME`
Given that, you can tell the runner to run a selected set of tags

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(tags = {"@TAGNAME"})
```

Is that what you were after?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but thanks for response. I was looking for examples of filtering cucumber tests when runing them via junit - filtering in junit and not with the help of Runwith controller. I wrote my own filter then.